# Opencv HoughCircles Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate memory in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError' for large image

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, hough-transform

I am getting this error when running openCV HoughCircle on large image

> Exception has occurred: error
> OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 278963136 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'
> File "C:\Users", line 17, in main
> circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8, param1=200, param2=100, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
> File "C:\Users", line 36, in 
> main(sys.argv[1:])
> Blockquote

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
def main(argv):
    
    default_file = 'image.png'
    filename = argv[0] if len(argv) > 0 else default_file
    # Loads an image
    src = cv2.imread(cv2.samples.findFile(filename), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 5)

    rows = gray.shape[0]
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8, param1=200, param2=100, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
    
    # if circles is not None:
    #     circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    #     for i in circles[0, :]:
    #         center = (i[0], i[1])
    #         # circle center
    #         cv2.circle(src, center, 1, (0, 100, 100), 3)
    #         # circle outline
    #         radius = i[2]
    #         cv2.circle(src, center, radius, (255, 0, 255), 3)
    
    
    cv2.imshow("detected circles", src)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try downsizing your image first.

```
scale = 0.5 // 50% of original image
width = int(gray.shape[1] * scale)
height = int(gray.shape[0] * scale)
dim = (width, height)    
cv2.resize(gray, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are importing a lot of images into the memory which is filling up memory completely.

So, the resolution here is to either reduce the size of images i.e resize them or reduce the number of images. For instance, if you are trying to read 100 images in a folder, just remove some of them let's say 50 and try again. It will work.